# Align hebrew letters in ordered list to the right

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I am styling articles which include ordered lists.
I am having trouble aligning list's letters to the right as accepted in hebrew (I.E. That is how ordered list are formatted in Microsoft Office Word).
I have tried playing with Css as attached to snippet.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: hebrew;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ol>
```

Wrong:

[image: Current and wrong]

Desired:

[image: Solution should be like]

**EDIT:**

I have come with the following "solution". Feel free to offer something less fragile.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: hebrew;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  counter-increment: num;
  display: flex;
}

li:before {
  content: '.' counter(num, hebrew);
  direction: ltr;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  min-width: 23px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT2:**

Another approach is this:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: hebrew;
  list-style-position: inside;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ol>
```

Unfortunately it looks a bit uglier.
Wish there was a way to combine the straightness of this attitude and the look of the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try a different way. See if the below code meets your requirements.

```css
ol {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    counter-reset: num;
    float: left;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: num;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content: '.' counter(num, hebrew);
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    right: -35px;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The look is awesome. However, numbers bigger equal then eleven become in reverse order: 'אי' instead of 'יא' etc...

Comment: Well. That's how it works this way and I don't think it can be done what you are asking with counter. And I guess אי is correct instead of יא.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. No it's incorrect. It should be like in screenshot.